# Google chrome losing focus after windows authentication popup window

Tags: google-chrome

Once i fill out the credential information to windows authentication popup in latest version of chrome 59.0.3071.115 (64-bit), I can't see caret (cursor) is blinking to any text box. Even if i set the focus using jquery or javascript still no luck. I have to click out side of that window in order get focus to see caret (cursor). Windows authentication popup working fine on IE,Edge & Firefox browser.

I have asked this question on chrome community to get answer. https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/vtLLzBjNc8k/l7ZOtIfxCQAJ

Comment: Is this issue happening on the old version of chrome browsers

Comment: @ThillaiNarayanan nope, It was working fine.

Comment: we removed the all the save passwords from chrome://settings/passwords. Now it worked for us

Comment: I don't have any saved password in chrome. I have always set this setting as off.

Comment: Would like to add this just started happening recently to us as well. What happens is, when you put in the credentials (saved or manually), the authentication dialog goes away but the page appears to not have focus. I can type directly into the first field and it works, but none of the onblur/focus events fire, and the cursor / field outline are gone.

Simply shift+tabbing to the URL bar and tabbing back restores the focus, so it has something to do with the document window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the next stable release of Chrome (version 61). They were not able to merge the fix in the current version (60) due to breaking changes. It has only been released in the [official beta release](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) and it does fix the problem.

Here's what you can do to fix the problem for now:

- Install the beta release for your client.
- Use one of the JavaScript workarounds described in the [issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739676) comments.
- Show the end users how to handle the problem by simply adding a new Chrome tab in the browser and then return to the problematic tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. End users are already opening new chrome tab in the browser and return to the problematic tab and everything works fine.

Comment: This issue has been fixed on latest google chrome Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)